# Is it possible to create a WebServer on iOS which is written in C++

Tags: c++, ios, swift, web-services, vapor

I want to run a WebServer on iOS. The Server has a REST-API I want to access with a different app. I am aware that there are swift-frameworks for that goal (like Vapor), although most of them are unmanaged or deprecated (e.g. GCDWebServer, CocoaHTTPServer).

I know that it is possible to include c/c++-code in a swift application, but are there limitations on what functionality is allowed/usable? Would it be possible to run a web server with this c++-component, or is it necessary to use swift and one of the mentioned frameworks?

If it is possible on a technical level, would it violate the requirements of the AppStore?

Comment: What is that REST API running on same device supposed to do? Why a REST API and not a library which can be reused across apps?

Comment: You could build a web server, but it won't be possible for it to respond to network request unless it is the foreground app.  You can't make requests to it while some other app is in the foreground because it can't accept network requests while it is in the background.  Implementation language is irrelevant

Comment: @kiner_shah because it has to be accesible over the local network

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, so with this limitation an implementation in c++ would be possible?

Comment: @simonsays, my question is, why run it over local network, instead of having a library which will do the same functionality? Is there a reason for this client-server architecture?

Comment: Ideally you would run some web/tcp/udp server on separate machine which is always available in same network and connect to using "https://ip_of_the_machie:port" as long as its running on same wifi network you would be to able to reach it. Now if client and server both are in same app then its possible. Running them separate apps would create issues as mentioned above.